# javascript problem in firefox

Tags: javascript, css

i'm using this javascript to toggle the visibility of some divs which have different ids. it works how i want in google chrome and even in internet explorer but in firefox when i hover the links the divs won't change their visibility.
       javascript:

```
function loaded() { // this one is called in the body tag
    about.style.visibility='visible';
    last = about;
}

function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (last!=e) {
        e.style.visibility = 'visible';        
        last.style.visibility='hidden';
        last = e;
    }
}
```

css for divs:

```
#about {
    background-color:#D580FE;
    width:850px;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;    
    margin-top:40px;
}

#portofoliu {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    width:850px;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;    
    margin-top:-500px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: @Bogdan Are you sure `toggle_visibility` is called in Firefox?

Comment: yes,i am sure. i call my functions using this <li><a href="#" onmouseover="toggle_visibility('about')">about</a></li>. am i doing it wrong? :-s

Comment: do you have a link to a test page?

Comment: Not going to select an answer?

Comment: none of the answers were correct. i solved my problem by changing the script.

Answer (score 0):

try switching from `visibility:visible` and `visibility:hidden` to `display:block` and `display:none`

so...

```
function loaded() { // this one is called in the body tag  
about.style.display='block';  
last = about;
```

}

```
function toggle_display(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if (last!=e) {
    e.style.display = 'block';        
    last.style.display='none';
    last = e;
}
```

}

css for divs:

```
#about {
background-color:#D580FE;
width:850px;
height:500px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;    
margin-top:40px;
```

}

```
#portofoliu {
background-color:#FF0000;
width:850px;
height:500px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;    
margin-top:-500px;
display:none;
```

}

Comment: i tried this and it works great in chrome and IE but in firefox it won't even hide the about div.

Answer (score -1):

- Try using another variable other than `e`.  It is used as the `window.event` variable in Firefox.
- Your code should work.
  If the mouseover event is not being fired, you have a problem in your JavaScript elsewhere.
- Either post a page somewhere, post more info, or download Firebug and debug it yourself.